# how do I format long config file lines

Tags: haproxy

my frontend section has a huge number of 'certs'. The entire line is about 320-400 bytes. The normal bash or shell line continuation does not work...

```
frontend haproxy_www                                                                                                                                                                         
        bind *:80                                                                                                                                                                            
        bind *:443 ssl crt cert1.pem crt cert2.pem crt cert3.pem crt cert4.pem
```

I tried (which did not work):

```
frontend haproxy_www                                                                                                                                                                         
        bind *:80                                                                                                                                                                            
        bind *:443 ssl \
crt cert1.pem \
crt cert2.pem \
crt cert3.pem \
crt cert4.pem
```

PS I read the doc and at the top of the doc where it describes the document format it does not mention `long line continuation` or anything close.

Comment: Why not putting all certs in a directory and point HAProxy to the directory?

Comment: Not sure how that works... but one recommendation that seems to be ok is concat the individual PEM files into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an slightly related question... asking about joining PEM files...  but one recommendation that seems to be ok is concat the individual PEM files into one. That'll do it.